# multiple time redirection issue

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to create a domain route for url redirection.

```
 Route::get('/', function () {
        $url = parse_url(Request::fullUrl());
        $domain = explode('.', $url['host']);
        $subdomain = $domain[0];
        $name = DB::table('users')->where('name', $subdomain)->first();
        // return (url('/') . '/?ref=' .$name->id);
         return Redirect::to(url('/') . '/?ref=' .$name->id);
        //dd($name); 
        // write the rest of your code.
    });
```

This script showing multiple time redirection

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't this just loop you infinitely? You are redirecting back to `/`, but with a GET param... but not doing anything to get out of it.

Comment: FunkyMonk91@no I am not doing any thing

Comment: "This script showing multiple time redirection" and it id doing it as expected. You are recursively redirecting to /

Comment: li Khalili @please help me How can I achieve This

Comment: Achieve what? what is your goal exactly?

Comment: Ali Khalili@I  am trying to redirect  on given url

Comment: _What_ given URL, _to_ what new URL? How hard is it to give a _proper_ problem description, instead of just giving bits and pieces all the time?

Comment: Currently you are redirecting back to `/`, which calls the same function. You adding a get parameter to the URL isn't changing anything, because you are not doing anything different. You always `return Redirect::to(url('/')`. You need to redirect to a different route or return a different value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing in your code is called infinite recursion.

```php
return Redirect::to(url('/') . '/?ref=' .$name->id);
```

this line is causing the redirects.

This is what is happening -

When someone is accessing your website's homepage, the / route is called, but in the route function you are instructing laravel to redirect to / again so you will be stuck in a infinite loop till you close the tab.

If i understand your question correctly, (You have not done a great job explaining)

What you should do -

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
        $url = parse_url(Request::fullUrl());
        $domain = explode('.', $url['host']);
        $subdomain = $domain[0];
        $name = DB::table('users')->where('name', '=', $subdomain)->first();

        return redirect('http://www.yourmaindomain.com?ref='.$name->id);
    });
```

Comment: piyush@it's working ,but problem is ---mysubdomain url is ,,www.sanjay.example.com and I am trying to redirect this www.sanjay.example.com?/user=23 , your current solution is redirect me www.example.com?/user=23

Comment: @sanjayyadav Is the .example same in the both urls or different?

Comment: Piyush@.example is same for both url

Comment: Piyush@yes its working May I know one thing can I use

Comment: @sanjayyadav what?